# GridLayout Программное размещение фрагментов

Tags: java, android, xml, android-sdk, grid-layout

Программно добавляю фрагменты в GridLayout, фрагменты по нажатию на них удаляются, можно ли сделать так чтобы они построчно тянулись к левому верхнему углу?[image] После удаления

[image: после удаления]

Comment: А нельзя сделать анимацию при удаление эл., как раз нужную вам?

Comment: @TimurMukhortov  Не знаю как это можно реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, удалять фрагменты надо было не `setVisibility(View.GONE)`, а `gridLayout.removeView`, тогда все фрашменты перемещаются к левому верхнему углу

Answer (score 3):

**Теория:**

Пример того что вы привели возможно реализовать с помощью `RecyclerView`, также посмотрите `RecyclerView GridLayoutManager`.

Вот хороший ответ на ваш вопрос, так же подробный Гайд как это сделать просто и быстро stackoverflow.com - [ссылка на ответ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40587168/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager-like-the)

**Update:**

Вам необходимо удалять данные из вашей коллекции, после чего уведомлять ваш адаптер об изменениях. Вам нужно реализовать метод `deleteItem` в `Adapter`(e), после чего можете использовать его в вашем `Activity`/`Fragment`(e)

```
void deleteItem(int index) {
    mDataset.remove(index);
    notifyItemRemoved(index);
}
```

Comment: Если будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

Comment: Скриншоты - это что уже есть, надо чтобы при удалении они передвигались к первому элементу. Удаляю с помощью `setVisibility(View.GONE)`